# Why is the "RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor" not reverting to default on the new and unselected text, after the SelectionBackColor was changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox`. I'm working on changing the `SelectionBackColor` only of the  selected text.

Then, I have a `ToolStripMenuItem`**(let's call it 'buttonA' for now)** which is responsible to change the `SelectionBackColor` of the selected text. The problem I'm facing is after I click buttonA, the background color of the selected text in the RichTextBox can be successfully done. However, when I add some other characters or text right after the changed background color text, it doesn't use the default background color. Instead, it continues to use the same background color as assigned from buttonA, which I don't want to happen.

At first, I thought that my start index and end index of the selected text was problematic. But, I don't think there's any problems in its codes. Below shows the code example:

```
SolidBrush textBgCol; //a variable to keep color

this.richTextBox1.Select = this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart, this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength;

this.richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(textBgCol.Color.A, textBgCol.Color.R, textBgCol.Color.G, textBgCol.Color.B);
```

---

1. One of my efforts was to change the `SelectionBackColor` to `default` in the `KeyDown` event of `richTextBox1`. However, the background color of the new or successive characters and text were still the same as assigned from buttonA. Below shows the code example:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = default;
}
```

2. I've also tried to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327153/c-sharp-richtextbox-remove-custom-selectionbackcolor) but, I don't think it helps me to solve my case here.
3. Other than that, just to confirm that my `richTextBox1`'s `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` were okay, I've even referred to these: [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183599/rich-text-box-how-to-highlight-text-block?noredirect=1&lq=1), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634236/how-to-read-selected-text-on-richtextbox), and [ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065616/how-to-select-richtextbox-text-given-an-index-and-length).

---

May I know any other workarounds for this please? Or, were there anything inside my codes that I've missed?

Comment: Why `.SelectionBackColor = default`?. Did you check what that is? Or `Color.Empty`? Try `richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox1.BackColor;`

Comment: @Jimi -- Still not working.

Comment: So, if you write in `KeyDown`, e.g., `if (richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor != richTextBox1.BackColor) { richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox1.BackColor; }`, does it enter the `if` block? Because it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment by @Jimi:

I just need to change the codes in my `richTextBox1`'s `KeyDown` event handler to:

```
if(richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor != richTextBox1.BackColor)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox1.BackColor;
}
```

Below shows the demo:
[image: theDemo]

Thanks!